# How to set startDestination in Navigation Component based on the fragment/nav_graph I come from?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Navigation Component with Kotlin, and have three main tabs in nav_dashboard - Explore, My Groups and Profile. When I start application the startDestination is nav_explore, but then I want to go from there to different screens eg. CreateGroupFragment/nav_create_group and from there I have button that I want to redirect me to nav_dashboard but with My Groups selected - I guess that then the startDestination needs to be nav_profile. But how I can I implement that?

Dashboard Fragment (it contains Fragment Container View in XML):

```
internal class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var navigator: DashboardNavigator

    private var _binding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null
    private val binding
        get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initBottomNavigation()
    }

    private fun initBottomNavigation() {
        with(binding.bottomNavigationView) {
            setupWithNavController(getDashboardNestedNavController())
        }
    }

    private fun getDashboardNestedNavController(): NavController {
        val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_container) as NavHostFragment
        val navGraph = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_dashboard_menu)
        navHostFragment.navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, bundle ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.exploreFragment, R.id.myGroupsFragment, R.id.profileFragment -> setBottomNavVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                else -> setBottomNavVisibility(View.GONE)
            }
        }

        return navHostFragment.navController
    }

    private fun setBottomNavVisibility(visibility: Int) {
        binding.bottomNavigationView.visibility = visibility
    }
}
```

nav_dashboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard_menu"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_explore">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_explore" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_my_groups" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_profile" />

</navigation>
```

nav_create_group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_create_group"
    app:startDestination="@id/createGroupFragment">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_create_group_map" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_my_groups" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/createGroupFragment"
        android:name="com.wojciechkula.locals.presentation.creategroup.CreateGroupFragment"
        android:label="@string/create_group_create_group"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_group">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/openMap"
            app:destination="@id/nav_create_group_map" />
<!--        Here I want another action to navigate to nav_dashboard with startDestination: nav_my_groups-->
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to change the startDestination.
Secondly, why are you using multiple graphs? That usually makes things more complicated!
Anyway, you can just set the selected tab manually.

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.tabId).isChecked = true
```

"tabId" is the id of the item in your bottom nav xml file.